# Non-interactive authentication to Azure AD from Xamarin

Tags: adal

We need to be able to perform non-interactive authentication to Azure AD using a username & password from our Xamarin mobile app.

Please refer to the following example which does the same but from a Windows desktop application:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless

Is this possible?

We have managed to perform interactive authentication to Azure AD from Xamarin but not non-interactive. We don't want to use the Microsoft Login Page User Interface.

Regards,
Andy

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? What have you tried? The auth calls required are in the sample, what happens if you make those calls from your Xamarin app?

Comment: We are getting the same exception and stack trace as reported on this Xamarin Forum post:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67195/authenticating-with-adal-and-webapi-without-using-user-credentials

The app crashes when calling AcquireTokenAsync and passing in a UserCredential object.

Answer (score 0):

In adal v3 we have removed the non-interactive authentication for every platform except desktop (only there for legacy reasons). No app should be collecting the creds and should be using the webview to delegate the authentication flow responsibility to AAD. Also, using non-interactive flow will fail when you enable multi-factor authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

What other options do we have? 

We want to use oAuth to secure our Web API in Azure and already have our own login user interface which has multi-factor authentication and account recovery facilities which we are keen to retain.

Comment: Are you a federated tenant?

Comment: No we aren't a federated tenant.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to integrate your own MFA and account recovery services into AAD as a replacement. I am curious though about the fact that if your identity is being managed by AAD then how are you consuming your custom MFA and recovery service currently?